# Is Sigma $\Sigma$ a mathematical way of doing a for loop?

Tags: summation, notation

I've been a programmer for ten years, and once upon a time I was pretty good at math. Those days are long gone. I'm taking some online classes and now I find myself needing to remember the math I learned in college and it has all gone bye-bye.

Specifically, I have a question about $\Sigma$ (Sigma):

In an $\Sigma$ equation, there is an N above the $\Sigma$, and an $i = 1$ (or some number) below. 
If someone could help my programmer mind - this looks like a *for loop* in programming. Is that essentially what is going on with everything inside the $()$ of the $\Sigma$? It simply computes all the values for each iteration from $i$ to N and then sums them all up?

Comment: Yes, this is what it means.

Comment: Essentially, yes.  [Read more on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation).  There do exist other ways of using it besides starting with $i=start$ and cycling through all integer values from $start$ to $end$.  For example the well known handshaking lemma in graph theory $\sum\limits_{v\in V}\deg(v)=2|E|$ which says that the sum of the degrees of the vertices in any graph must equal twice the number of edges.  Here, we use an indexing set, $V$, and cycle over all elements, $v$, in that set.

Comment: Basically, but it is a bit more flexible, because you can sum up _countably_ many terms, which means you can even add infinitely many terms (known as a Series). Though it may or may not converge to a meaningful value (this question has been much studied over the years).

Comment: I should add, the multiplication has an analogous symbol, a capital Greek letter pi: $\Pi$

Comment: @JustinBenfield $\prod$ `\prod`

Comment: In C++ like for{i=a,i<=n,i++} where a is the starting value

Comment: @JMoravitz: Some programming languages allow this form too. For example, in C++ you can say "for (auto v: V") if V is a container.

Comment: @Archis: two mistakes: `{` should be `(`, and `,` should be `;`. Very sloppy!

Comment: The great difference is that a Σ does not actually compute anything at all.  A lot of the uses you see, especially early on in math, are easily computable, and no one spends much time a series if they do not at least hope to be able to compute something about it.  But there is no requirement that the terms of the sum be computable in any sense, let alone that you know how to compute them, or that you can find their sum,

Comment: hmm right @ Tony k

Comment: Has anyone mentioned the alternative definition $\sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ or $\sum_{x \in A}$ notation?

Comment: It's a bit more subtle than "adding them up." In a For loop, it's a process taking place in time. We do add things up, one at a time. In a summation, it happens all at once. The summation expression *is* the sum, it doesn't become it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Well yeah, *sort of*. But not *really*, IMO.

What most programming languages do is a awkward, mathematically speaking. An imperative for-loop *increments a variable*. That shouldn't really be possible: maths doesn't know *time*. If you define something once then it'll conceptually hold *always*, i.e. if you start out with $i = 0$ it's not possible to later have $i=3$.

What's really going on, mathematically, is that you write an *abstraction*, an expression *for all $i$*. Then you apply to that expression the higher-order operation “sum over all such $i$ in some range”. The variable $i$ never actually has any particular value, it's just a placeholder for “consider value here”.

There is a proper mathematical framework that can nicely express computations like a sum. It's called [lambda calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus). In this, such an *abstraction over some variable* is called a *lambda expression*, written like<sup>*</sup>
$$
  \lambda i \mapsto \frac1{2^i}
$$
More commonly, this kind of abstraction would be called a *function* and written
$$
  f : \mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{Q}, \quad f(i) = \frac{1}{2^i}
$$
or, in programming languages, something like

```
double f(int i) {
  return 1.0 / 2**i;
}
```

Now, what a summation operator does is, it takes such a lambda function and yields a number equal to the function evaluated with all possible arguments in a range and summed up. For instance,
$$
S = \sum_{i=0}^{5}\frac1{2^i}
$$
is in a sense shorthand notation for something
$$
S = \Sigma(0,5,f).
$$
Note that I didn't write $f(i)$ but just $f$: this is *not* the result of applying $f$ to any particular $i$, but the *function object* $f$ itself. It is not a number but, well, a function.

It's not necessary to first give $f$ a name and then use it in the sum, I can also just put in the lambda expression:
$$
S = \Sigma(0,5,\lambda i\mapsto 1/2^{i}).
$$
I understand sums as a special way of writing this expression.

Now as for how to the summation operator can actually be implemented in a computer? Well: in an imperative language, a for-loop would certainly be a reasonably way to do it. Like<sup>†</sup>,

```
double sumFromTo(int i0, int iend, function<double(int)> f) {
  int i;
  double result;
  for(i=0; i<=iend; ++i) {
    result += f(i);
  }
  return result;
}
```

But as I said, mathematically it doesn't really make sense to *change the value* of a variable. However, it is possible to define the equivalent of such a loop directly in lambda-calculus: through *recursion*. This requires [some a bit weird definitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_combinator) to use it in the original maths/logic setting, but can also be written in programming languages:

```
double sumFromTo_rec(int i, int iend, function<double(int)> f) {
  if (i<=iend)
    return f(i) + sumFromTo_rec(i+1, iend, f);
   else
    return 0;
}
```

Now, in the recursive call, `i` will have the value of `i+1` from the outer call. So, am I doing mathematically unsound mutation here again? *No actually*! The `i` function argument is only an abstraction. In the inner function call, it's simply *a different* variable, which just happens to also be called `i` (but that's an irrelevant implementation detail).

You may well think this silly. If the computer can just re-use the same variable `i` by incrementing it, why should we bother with defining a new one? You'd be right in a way. `sumFromTo_rec` would in fact be inefficient in a language like C, because the computer would have to allocate an actual new integer on the stack in each function call.

However, quite practically speaking, mutating variables also opens up numerous possibilities for programming bugs. [Functional programming language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming) therefore eschew (or [entirely forbid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purely_functional)) this. These languages have come up with various optimisations like [tail-calls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call) to avoid the overhead of allocating new variables in every recursive call (so basically, you write clean mathematical semantics but under the hood the same memory is actually re-used, like it would be in an imperative language).

If you're a mathematically-interested programmer (or a computation-interested mathematician) I recommend you check out [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/). It's a modern functional programming language with very clean semantics, yet great performance and good compatibility to “real world applications”. The above recursive summation would in Haskell look as simple as

```
sumFromTo i₀ iEnd f
    | i₀<=iEnd   = f i₀ + sumFromTo (i₀+1) iEnd f
    | otherwise  = 0
```

That's similar enough to how the rigorous recursive definition of $\sum$ in maths notation would look:
$$
  \sum_{i=i_0}^{i_{\text{end}}} f(i)
 = \begin{cases}
       f(i_0) + \sum_{i=i_0+1}^{i_{\text{end}}}f(i)
           & \text{if $i_0 < i_{\text{end}}$}
    \\ 0   & \text{otherwise}
   \end{cases}
$$
Observe that $f(i)$ as such is never actually evaluated: it's always $f(i_0)$ (however, that variable has a different value in each recursion level). This is better reflected in a programming language than it is in the maths notation: the former really make a point of *not* applying $f$ to anything when you're talking about the function itself, rather then the result from applying that function to any particular argument.

---

<sup>*</sup><sub>The classical standard notation in lambda calculus is actually $\lambda i.\ 1/{2^i}$, but I reckon the arrow makes it clearer what's going on than a dot. Most programming languages use an arrow symbol if they offer lambda functions, e.g. in Haskell you'd write</sub>

```
sumFromTo 0 6 (\i -> 1/2^i)
```

<sup>†</sup><sub>Unlike in maths, it's generally preferred in programming (except in Fortran and Matlab, which I don't consider very well-designed) to express the range *with upper bound excluded*. This turns out to be the most useful convention in practice; see [what famous Dijkstra wrote on the matter](https://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/EWD/transcriptions/EWD08xx/EWD831.html).</sub>

Comment: Very clear! Can you write the explicit definition of the "$\sum$" function (i.e. the assigning mechanism behinds) in mathematical expression? And it modern mathematics, the essence of the "$\sum$" function is always considered by lambda calculus?

Comment: So is there truly NO so-called *variables* in mathematics? Why can't mathematics adopt this "_vary_" idea? What is the flaws and disasters when we do so? Thanks!

Comment: And, to study lambda calculus and Y-combinators and so on, which book you recommend? Thanks!

Comment: @Eric: mathematics can adapt this “vary idea”. A quite obvious, but hardly useful way to do it is to not consider a single value, but a whole _history_ of values. This history as a whole never changes, you just consider different points in it! An often better approach is to focus on the _state changes_ between the single steps. Values of “state change type” can be chained together with purely functional terms, using concepts from category theory (the mapping “types of constant values → types of state-change values” is a [monad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monad_(functional_programming))).

Answer (score 7):

Yes, sort of. By (recursive) definition,
$$\sum_{i=0}^0 a_i := a_0 $$ and
 $$\sum_{i=0}^n a_i :=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} a_i + a_n $$
or, sloppily, $$\sum_{i=0}^n a_i :=a_0 + a_1+ \dots +a_n$$

Answer (score 5):

In Mathematica I frequently switch between the Sum and the Table commands like in these examples:

**Example 1:**

$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{n=1} 1 = 1 = 1 $

$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{n=2} 1 = 2 = 1+1 $

$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{n=3} 1 = 3 = 1+1+1 $

$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{n=4} 1 = 4 = 1+1+1+1 $

$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{n=5} 1 = 5 = 1+1+1+1+1 $

```
Sum[1,{n,1,5}]
```

which outputs: 5

compared to:

```
Table[1,{n,1,5}]
```

which outputs: {1,1,1,1,1}

**Example 2:**

$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{n=1} n = 1 = 1 $

$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{n=2} n = 3 = 1+2$

$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{n=3} n = 6 = 1+2+3$

$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{n=4} n = 10 = 1+2+3+4$

$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{n=5} n = 15 = 1+2+3+4+5$

```
Sum[n,{n,1,5}]
```

which outputs: 15

compared to:

```
Table[n,{n,1,5}]
```

which outputs: {1,2,3,4,5}

**Example 3:**

$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{n=1} \frac{n(n+1)}{2} = 1 = 1$

$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{n=2} \frac{n(n+1)}{2} = 4 = 1+3$

$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{n=3} \frac{n(n+1)}{2} = 10 = 1+3+6$

$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{n=4} \frac{n(n+1)}{2} = 20 = 1+3+6+10$

$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{n=5} \frac{n(n+1)}{2} = 35 = 1+3+6+10+15$

```
Sum[n*(n+1)/2,{n,1,5}]
```

which outputs: 35

compared to:

```
Table[n*(n+1)/2,{n,1,5}]
```

which outputs: {1, 3, 6, 10, 15}

I don't know if it is a good answer to your question though.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, indeed.

For example:

$$\sum_{i = 1}^n\frac{x_i}{n}$$

is generally considered the average (mean) of a series $\{x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4, ... x_i\}$.

That would translate to a foreach over an array that divides all the values by the `array.length`, and sums them all up.

Hope this helped!

Comment: You mean $\sum_{i = 1}^n\frac{x_i}{n}$, not $\sum_{i = 0}^n\frac{x_i}{n}$. (Although $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i = 1}^n x_i$ is more natural.)

Comment: @TonyK Thanks for that correction! Fixed.

Comment: Actually, as written this translates to a foreach that takes each number, *divides it by $n$*, and adds these all together. What you've described (where the numbers are summed, and *then* the sum is divided by the number) would be $\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i}{n}$.

Comment: Which is the same thing! (I think... lemme just correct it)

Answer (score 2):

Definitely yes.

The mathematician would write it like this:

$\sum\limits_{i=m}^n f(i)$

And the programmer would write it like this:

```
result = 0
for (i=m; i<=n; i++) {
    result += f(i)
}
```

You can think of `m` as the `start index` and `n` as the `end index`.

Comment: It would actually be `for (i=m; i<=n; ++k)` to match the sum $\sum_{i=m}^n$ (which includes $n$). Anyway, as I argued above, this is problematic: a mathematical sum has no _direction_. In a C-like language, `f` could in principle alter some global state so you'd get a different result depending of which direction the loop goes. And, how would you express a sum like $\sum_{i=-\infty}^\infty f(i)$?

Comment: I would argue that just because a computer couldn't deliver a result when executing the code doesn't mean that you couldn't express this thing in a programming language. The only problem I see would be that we don't have infinite amounts of memory and thus probably no one has implemented a symbol for infinity yet.

Comment: `i <= n` should be the continue criterion.

Comment: If you think about it, the code doesn't even really represent what the computer will be doing because it would get compiled and optimized. So I would really look at it as a whole.

Comment: FTR, I just noticed I made the same `<=` vs `<` mistake in my original answer...

Answer (score 1):

The $\Sigma$ symbol allows to represent sums with a variable number of terms. Alternatively we can write

$$\sum_{i=1}^N a_i=a_1+a_2+\cdots a_N,$$ but the LHS is more compact. There are similar notations for the product $\prod_{i=1}^N$, logical conjunction $\bigwedge_{i=1}^N$, disjunction $\bigvee_{i=1}^N$, set intersection $\bigcap_{i=1}^N$, union $\bigcup_{i=1}^N$...

There is a slight difference with for-loop statements found in the procedural programming languages: there is no order of evaluation. This is made possible by the fact that there is no "side effect" when "evaluating" the terms.

The notation with $i=1$ and $N$ indeed denotes the discrete range $[1,N]$, and $N<1$ normally implies a zero sum.

In some cases, other "looping" conditions are used, such as

$$\sum_{i=1,\text{ prime }i}^N$$ or 
$$\sum_{i\in P}$$

Comment: Silent downvoters aren't my friends.