# Explaining Sigma-Notation

Tags: summation, notation

today, I attempted to introduce the summation notation $\Sigma$ to my students. The notation was unfamiliar to the students beforehand. I worked through many examples with them, but for most of them, working with such an abstract notation remains challenging. Do you have any suggestions on how to best teach someone who has very little prior knowledge of math? What is the most intuitive method to introduce this notation? I also tried using a for loop, but it didn't seem to help.

Comment: $\sum_{k=1}^n(\cdot )_k$ is shorthand for saying we are adding all elements in $(\cdot)$ in the range $k = 1, 2, \dots, n$. You can extend the definition to elements $k$ in a set $S$.

Comment: @Gregory too abstract for my students. I need a some more intuitive definition

Comment: This is not the right place, it should be posted on math educators.i

Comment: @Andrew But I can't post questions there. It only offers courses.

Comment: Have you tried the recursive definition? Otherwise I would use a list (like in computer science) and let them code the sum of a list, then try to say that $\operatorname{sum} (L) = \Sigma_{x \in L} x$, maybe this would work? Here $L$ is the list

Comment: You write that you "worked through many examples" but how did you introduce and explain the notation?

Comment: @wayne You can absolutely post questions on https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Cross posted at https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/26755/explaining-sigma-notation

Comment: Closely related: [Is Sigma Σ
a mathematical way of doing a for loop?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1694311/is-sigma-sigma-a-mathematical-way-of-doing-a-for-loop/)

Answer (score 2):

The main difficulty is not the notation $\sum$ itself, but the use of bound variables, especially when combined with other variables.
I would simply explain it using  a series of simple examples and then ask the students to design their own examples:
\begin{align*}
\sum_{x = 1}^5 x \quad&\text{is a shortcut for $1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5$}.\\
\sum_{i = 1}^5 i \quad&\text{is also a shortcut for } 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 \\
\sum_{x = -1}^2 x \quad&\text{is a shortcut for } -1 + 0 + 1 + 2 \\
\sum_{x = 1}^5 x^2 \quad&\text{is a shortcut for } 1^2 + 2^2 + 3^2 + 4^2 + 5^2 \\
\sum_{x = -1}^2 x^2 \quad&\text{is a shortcut for } (-1)^2 + 0^2 + 1^2 + 2^2 \\
\sum_{x = 3}^5 (3x-1) \quad&\text{is a shortcut for } (3 * 3-1) + (3*4-1) + (3*5-1) \\
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

Frame challenge.

Why introduce that notation at all?

Whenever I see a summation I want to understand I unpack it and write the first few terms (and the last if it's a finite sum) with an ellipsis. I (try) never (to) manipulate those expressions, or play with the index of summation.

If you must teach that notation because your students will encounter it in their reading, teach how to read it that way. Don't ask or expect them to write it.

Comment: "Why introduce that notation at all?" Because it's massively useful at expressing lots of common computations in a way that's both precise and concise. Also because it's a good introduction to the more general idea of higher-order operators, instead of fuzzy induction from examples.

Comment: @leftaroundabout I agree that the sigma notation is useful and concise. To my taste too concise - I can only read it  when i replace it with ellipses. When I write a paper I know I have to use it - and suspect many of  my readers have to undo the concision just as I do. That's what I want my students to know - when they need to know it. So, for example, I would rather not use it for Riemann sums in introductory calculus. There it just gets in the way of the ideas.